# Cannot transfer ownership of ERC20 contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

My contract source code likes below:

```
contract StandardToken
{
  uint256 totalSupply;
  ...
}
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;
  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}
contract MyToken is StandardToken, Ownable {
     string public name ;
     string public symbol ;
     uint8  public decimals ;
     function MyToken(
            uint256 tokenInitialSupply,
            string tokenName,
            string tokenSymbol,
            uint8 tokenDecimals,
         ) public {
         totalSupply = tokenInitialSupply.mul( 10**uint256(tokenDecimals));
         name = tokenName;
         symbol = tokenSymbol;
         decimals = tokenDecimals;
         balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
     }
     ...
     function getowner() public view returns (address) {
            return owner;
       }
}
```

I use the js code below to transfer ownership:

```
var tokenAddress = "0xc11b5692d92c5a5f72c5286caaaf27281ff23cc4";
var ownerAddr = "0xf05b0e099cbbb7805cef0c3a822ae2d3b49040ce";
var targetOwnerAddr = "0x700fac5cb73979f0d64b9b410b14a214146f1df1";

var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
const main = async () => {
    var abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/root/abi/mytoken.json', 'utf-8'));
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tokenAddress );
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(ownerAddr, "********", 600);

    //current owner address
    var currOwnerAddr = await contract.methods.getowner().call();
    console.log(`current owner address: ${currOwnerAddr}`);

    //transfer owner
    await contract.methods.transferOwnership(targetOwnerAddr).call({from: ownerAddr});

    //new owner address
    var newOwnerAddr = await contract.methods.getowner().call();
    console.log(`new owner address: ${newOwnerAddr}`);
}
main();
```

However, the log below shows owner is unchanged:

```
current owner address: 0xF05B0e099CbBB7805CEF0C3A822aE2D3B49040ce
new owner address: 0xF05B0e099CbBB7805CEF0C3A822aE2D3B49040ce
```

So would you help point out where the problem is?Many THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
await contract.methods.transferOwnership(targetOwnerAddr).call({from: ownerAddr});
```

To this:

```
await contract.methods.transferOwnership(targetOwnerAddr).send({from: ownerAddr});
```

And of course, you'll need to make sure that account `ownerAddr` is unlocked on the node that you're communicating with...

Please read some more about [call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) and [send](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).

Comment: THANKS! It works! what's the difference between call() and send() method?

Comment: @Ntydrm: I've added a couple of links in the answer. Please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the V.

Comment: Checked the links, very clear.thanks again.